# Trying to implement local storage in React. It is not tracking the input value that I send

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a local storage in REACT in order to save in a database the data(numbers) that I type in the input. The code works when I check it in the console.log but it does not work as I wish.

Every time I add a value it deletes the previous one. So I can just read the last input that I put. It does not shows me all the inputs that I put before. I would like to mention that this component is rendered dynamically so in the parent component I get four different buttons where I can type the number that I want to. Thanks in advance

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Stake() {
    const [stakes, setStakes] = useState([]);

    const addStake = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newStake = {
            input: e.target.stake.value,
        };
        setStakes([...stakes, newStake]);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const json = JSON.stringify(stakes);
        localStorage.setItem("stakes", json);
    }, [stakes]);

    console.log(stakes)
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={addStake}>
                <input style={{ marginLeft: "40px", width: "50px" }} type="text" name="stake" required />
                {/* <button style={{ marginLeft: "40px" }} type="submit">OK</button> */}
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Stake;
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your component always starts with an empty array: `useState([])`.

When the component renders for the first time, you need to retrieve existing values from locaStorage and set it as the local state of component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const stakes= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("stakes")) || [];
    setStakes(stakes);
}, []);
```

Comment: I am getting an error stakes is not iterable

Comment: Ah yes, you just need to add a safe guard for when localStorage is empty like an `if(){}` or `|| []`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-tdd-20uf2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Now it works, but not completely. This component is rendered 4 times, so I get 4 different databases. How can I group all the inputs in a common database?Thanks in advance

Comment: There is only one `stakes` in localstorage and local state. I don't know what you mean by databases. Also feel free to ask new questions if you encounter new problems, it is encouraged on this site

Comment: because in the parent component I have four stakes and this creates 4 array in the local storage instead of saving all the inputs in one array

Comment: It creates one array with 4 objects. That is because you wrote this: `const newStake = {input: e.target.stake.value, }; setStakes([...stakes, newStake]);`.  If you just want one array you can simply do `const setStakes([...stakes, e.target.stake.value]);`

Comment: I still get four objs. What should I do in order to put all the values n one array?thanks again

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. This is why it is a good idea to ask separate questions, it needs more context, in this case your parent components